# Creating awaitable tasks using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I want to create a collection of awaitable tasks, so that I can start them together and asynchronously process the result from each one as they complete.

I have this code, and a compilation error:

`> cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable`

If I understand well, the tasks return by `Select` don't have a return type, even though the delegate passed returns `ColetaIsisViewModel`, I would think:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    Task.Run(LoadItems);
}

async Task LoadItems()
{
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Directory.GetDirectories(somePath)
                            .Select(dir => new Task(() =>
                                new ItemViewModel(new ItemSerializer().Deserialize(dir))));

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        var result = await task;  // <-- here I get the compilation error
        DoSomething(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, never use new Task – instead use Task.Run for to wrap CPU-bound operations. Second you need to define tasks as IEnumerable<Task<ItemViewModel>>, i.e. provide the type the tasks will return.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't ever use the `Task` constructor.

Since you're calling synchronous code (`Deserialize`), you could use `Task.Run`:

```
async Task LoadItems()
{
  var tasks = Directory.GetDirectories(somePath)
      .Select(dir => Task.Run(() =>
           new ItemViewModel(new ItemSerializer().Deserialize(dir))));

  foreach (var task in tasks)
  {
    var result = await task;
    DoSomething(result);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ:

```
void LoadItems()
{
  var vms = Directory.GetDirectories(somePath)
      .AsParallel().Select(dir =>
           new ItemViewModel(new ItemSerializer().Deserialize(dir)))
      .ToList();

  foreach (var vm in vms)
  {
    DoSomething(vm);
  }
}
```

Or, if you make `Deserialize` a truly `async` method, then you can make it all asynchronous:

```
async Task LoadItems()
{
  var tasks = Directory.GetDirectories(somePath)
      .Select(async dir => 
           new ItemViewModel(await new ItemSerializer().DeserializeAsync(dir))));

  foreach (var task in tasks)
  {
    var result = await task;
    DoSomething(result);
  }
}
```

Also, I recommend that you do not use fire-and-forget in your constructor. [There are better patterns for asynchronous constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: It was pretty fun to see all the updates in real time. Excellent answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just changed `new Task` to `Task.Run()` and everything worked. By the way, I am reading content from files and populating an ObservableCollection displayed with a ListBox. But there is still one thing: it looks like the tasks are running asynchronously one after the other. I changed the `foreach` to `Parallel.foreach` and it got worse: UI is updated only after _all_ the tasks run to completion. What can I do to fire every task at the same time so that I get the minimum total elapsed time between operation start and last task completed?

Comment: Ok, regarding my previous comment, looks like the `AsParallel` alternative you provided works. Still, it feels like tasks get completed "in batches", I believe this is because task duration is very similar, and cores are assigned work all at once per batch. Does it make sense?

Comment: @heltonbiker: If you want to process items as they complete, you should call `DoSomething` from within the `Task.Run`: `Select(dir => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(new ItemViewModel(new ItemSerializer().Deserialize(dir))))`. Note that `DoSomething` will be called in parallel, and it's up to you to update the ObservableCollection appropriately. This approach is simpler if you make it all truly async as per the last example.

Comment: @StephenCleary  On the second sample, when using `AsParallel` it should be blocking the thread before the iteration on `vms`, right?

Comment: @ibubi: Yes; when the code hits the `ToList`, it will wait for all the parallel operations to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has been answered, but you can always do this too:

```
 var serializer = new ItemSerializer();
 var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(somePath);
 foreach (string directory in directories)
 {
      await Task.Run(() => serializer.Deserialize(directory))
      .ContinueWith(priorTask => DoSomething(priorTask.Result));                
 }
```

Notice I pulled out the serializer instantiation (assuming there are no side effects).

Comment: That's an interesting solution too. I found it particularly clean and I am planning to try it as soon as I have some opportunity. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should refactor this to [use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). `ContinueWith` is a low-level, dangerous API.